# How to make a switch and scroll effect with javascript and css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I want to make a scroll effect to my web page:

The content of my page:

```
<div id="first">
     Content 1
     <a href="#second">Switch</a>
</div>
<div id="second">
     Content 2
</div>
```

Obviously, when I click to `Switch`, the browser screen will switch from `div#first` to `div#second` immediately.

However, I want to create an effect that make `div#first` to switch smoothly and slide to `div#second` (not immediately). Moreover, I also want to create a scroll effect. When the users are in `div#first` and scroll down, the browser screen will automatically slide to `div#second` and vice verse.

How can I do that with javascript (or jQuery if necessary)?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to search and did not find an answer. How can you come up with your code when you don't know where to start??

Comment: I am not asking people to code for me completely. what I am asking is a suggestion, a way to start. I think you should remove your "-1" if you understand my intention. Thank you!

Comment: Try searching SO (or at least some more assuming you have already). I have no doubts that this has come up before,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using `animate` method

```
$("a").click(function(){
   $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#second").offset().top
   }, 900);
})
```

Here is the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xhn7qcxh/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much! It is a lot better for people to have the right answers for their questions, not some useless arguments.